# Boot problem(boot deleted accidentally)

Tags: boot

I have ubuntu installed as my daily driver. I used gparted to format a Usb but instead i formated the boot disk accidentally( its size is 500mib). I did some research online. I tried boot repair when I booted with USB live. It's indicated me : it's actually repaired. There some warning: " your bios is uefi but no uefi partition detect. Create uefi partition". When I unplugged the USB live and try to boot. It's redirected me to the bios with no boot found. But the weird thing.  The whole disk is there. I didn't formatted though. When I use `fdisk -l` i can see it.
If anyone can help. But the way my pc is Asus x541u.

Comment: Did you have UEFI boot and an ESP - efi system partition? Or did you just have BIOS boot? If Windows was pre-installed and system from after 2012 it is UEFI, but you can install or re-install in either mode. Post your `sudo fdisk -l` above in question to preserve formatting. Asus x541ua Update of UEFI & SSD firmware solved issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414431 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420860

Answer (score 0):

This also happend to my sister.
I solved it like this:
1.Make Ubuntu install USB/DVD
2.Folow install steps  nornaly until you came to Configure partitions step.
3.Check if other partitions are OK, and create **Only EFI partition**
4. Finish installation steps normaly(like you did when you first install Ubuntu).
This solve my sister's problem, If you have any question just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a uefi partition.

Boot in live cd/USB and launch gparted.

Select the right hard drive. You should see it's empty at the left.

Create a new FAT32 partition at the left of the drive and add those flags to it: "boot"; "esp". Mount the partition as /boot/efi.

[image]

Apply the changes and you should be able to boot again.